# Why do we define C++ types as void for the Objective-C compiler in LLVM (while it is okay for the C++ compiler to see objective-C interfaces)?

Tags: c++, objective-c, compilation, header, clang

I was going through the source of an iOS project that uses a C++ library when I stumbled upon this few rather interesting lines of code in the header file of a Objective-C wrapper for C++:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
#ifndef __cplusplus
typedef void VisageTracker;
typedef void FaceData;
typedef void DemoFrameGrabber;
typedef void FDP;
typedef void VsImage;
#endif
#endif

@interface TrackerWrapper : NSObject {
CustomGLView *glView;
#ifdef __cplusplus
    VisageSDK::VisageTracker* tracker;
    VisageSDK::FaceData trackingData;
    DemoFrameGrabber *demoFrameGrabber;
    DemoObserver *demoObserver;
    int glWidth;
    int glHeight;
    bool inGetTrackingResults;
#endif
}
```

A question immediately hit me: Why are all the C++ types such as `VisageTracker, FaceData, DemoFrameGrabber, FDP, VsImage` being defined as `void` for the Objective-C compiler?

I'm quite curious as how LLVM does the compilation here. It appears that the header file would be gone through twice, once by a C++ compiler and once by a Objective-C compiler.

Question: why must we hide the C++ types from the Objective-C compiler, but the C++ compiler is okay seeing an objective-C interface (and not only that but we can also "inject" C++ stuff into the interface)?

### Update:

I tried removing these lines

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
#ifndef __cplusplus
typedef void VisageTracker;
typedef void FaceData;
typedef void DemoFrameGrabber;
typedef void FDP;
typedef void VsImage;
#endif
#endif
```

after which the code didn't fail to compile: it appears to work just fine without these lines. Therefore I conclude that these lines are probably there because

1. In an older version of Clang there's a bug in the type system which can be fixed by adding these lines.

or/and

2. It is an old tradition passed down from generation to generation with the belief that blinding the Objective-C compiler this way it can save some memories perhaps.

Answer (score -1):

Because `C++` and `Objective-C` is different languages.
They can be used both only in `Objective-C++`.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of that. But that doesn't answer the question of why we are hiding the C++ types.

Comment: @Arch to hide `C++` types from `Objective-C`.